# How to disable common name check in SSLContext in java?

Tags: java, ssl, jersey, jax-rs, ssl-certificate

I am using `SSLContext` so set up Jersey client, and need to disable the common name check in order to avoid unnecessary issues. However, I can find no documentation as to how we can do it correctly. So is the common name check disabled by default in `SSLContext` (assuming using TLS) or do we need to explicitly disable it? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: There is no `cn` check in `SSLContext`. It is done by the installed `HostnameVerifier`. Hostname checking is part of HTTPS, not of SSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you can accomplish what you are trying to do by implementing a [`HostnameVerifier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/HostnameVerifier.html), and just returning `true` in the `verify` method. You can set up the verifier on the [`ClientBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html). For example

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        .hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier)
        .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not answer your question, but it tells you that what you are doing is a bad idea and probably caused by a misunderstanding of how verification works.

> ...need to disable the common name check in order to avoid unnecessary issues

I don't know what the "unnecessary issues" are which you are trying to avoid, but not verifying the hostname is more or less that same as disabling all validation and thus make it possible to incorporate the server and/or to do man-in-the-middle attacks.

If you don't verify the hostname but still validate the certificate trust chain the attacker can now simply use a certificate signed by a trusted CA for the attackers own site, e.g. `attacker.example.com`. CA's will issue such certificate since the attacker can prove ownership of its own site.

Using its own certificate the attacker can now incorporate all the other sites, since the trust chain is valid even if the hostname is not. This is the same as if you would accept any kind of identification issued by a state, without even looking if the picture in the I.D. matches the person showing the I.D.

Comment: I agree. I guess I should've put a disclaimer [in there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30856567/2587435) somewhere :-)